# How do I redirect to a WIX site but mask the URL?

Tags: url-routing, redirect

I have my homepage for an app hosted through Wix @ www.example.com.

My app is hosted through AWS at 54.108.252.000.

Every time a new user signs up a page is generated for them at 54.108.252.000/user_name.

I want to be able to set up redirects so that users can access their web page at www.example.com/user_name (instead of 54.108.252.000/user_name) but want to be able to continue to manage my home page via WIX at www.example.com.

My thought was to point my domain at 54.108.252.000 and then set an auto redirect on the home page to the WIX address (example.wixsite.com/home) however I'm not sure how to do this without exposing the the WIX address?